# Round Off decimal values in C#

Tags: c#, decimal, numbers, rounding

how do i round off decimal values ?
Example :

decimal Value = " 19500.98"

i need to display this value to textbox with rounded off like " 19501 "

if decimal value = " 19500.43"

then

value = " 19500 "

Comment: There is more than one way to round numbers, depending on the application domain you need to be careful to use the right kind of rounding at the right time.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Look at [`Math.Round(decimal)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s2d3xkk.aspx) or [the overload which takes a `MidpointRounding` argument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131274.aspx).

Of course, you'll need to parse and format the value to get it from/to text. If this is input entered by the user, you should probably use `decimal.TryParse`, using the return value to determine whether or not the input was valid.

```
string text = "19500.55";
decimal value;
if (decimal.TryParse(text, out value))
{
    value = Math.Round(value);
    text = value.ToString();
    // Do something with the new text value
}
else
{
    // Tell the user their input is invalid
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Math.Round( value, 0 )

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
 var someValue=123123.234324243m;
 var strValue=someValue.ToString("#");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = decimal.Round(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Total = Math.Ceiling(value)
```

Reply if it helps you

Comment: Ceiling rounds it up. `19500.43` will become `19501`, and not `19500` like the OP intended.

Comment: yes so if you want to round off amount if it is greater that 0.5 then u can use    Math.Round(Value, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

Answer (score 0):

```
string text = "19500.55";
text =(decimal.TryParse(text, out value))? (Math.Round(decimal.Parse(text))).ToString():"Invalid input";
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to OP's problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.